# Is it possible to route only part of the traffic through Cisco VPN client?

Tags: windows, vpn, cisco, cisco-vpn

I have windows Cisco VPN client v5. When I connect, it is cutting my machine from all the network, and I'm virtually in my employers network. Is it possible to send part of the traffic not through the VPN tunnell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to use the Shrew Soft VPN client (http://shrew.net/software), you could set your profile up in such a way to only route traffic destined for your work network over the VPN. That is accomplished by un-checking "Obtain topology automatically or tunnel all" in the Policy tab for the profile. But then you have to know what networks on the other end you need to connect to and manually specify them.

This is of course is possible only if you can get the group password and related settings out of your network admin.

Furthermore, this information indicates that it is technically possible, but obviously **you need to comply with your company's security policies and procedures**. If they think they need to route all of your traffic through their VPN, you need to think twice about how you are using the connection (in terms of what you're looking at, what computers [at home?] you are using it on, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean what's known as 'split-tunnelling' or 'split-DNS' where certain traffic does or does not go down the VPN. Getting this working usually requires changes by network/VPN staff as well as client setting changes, i.e. I'm not sure you can configure this on your own. Why not ask your own technical team, I'm sure they'd be happy to listen.

Comment: What should I change in the client?

Comment: there's literally no way to tell without knowing your network and client setup - that's why I suggest speaking to your own people - they'll know.